# How to quickly assign an attribute value to all products in a category, in Magento

Tags: mysql, magento-1.9

I would like to quickly update all products assigned to a particular category in Magento with a particular attribute/value. For example, all products in category Bed > Designer Bedding would have their google_product_category attribute value set to 2541. Anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: Do you mean where category is Bed or Designer Bedding?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your [WHERE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) clause would be based on your question but, you could use something similar to the following (and adjust as needed)

```
UPDATE [table] SET google_product_category = 2541 WHERE category = 'Bed'
```